# Python Attribute error

Tags: python, attributes

having problems with this error in python:

```
File "F:\dykrstra", line 36, in route
while node.label != node.prevNode.label:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'
```

Inside this while loop:

```
 while node.label != node.prevNode.label:
    node = node.prevNode
    labels.append(node.label)
```

I think it relates to this:

```
   def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.neighbours = []
        self.distances = []
        self.prevNode = None
        self.totalDistance = 0
```

I'm not sure why prevNode doesn't like the nothing being assigned to it, please help.

Comment: It is totally fine that you assign `None` to `prevNode`. But the value `None` has to attributes, so `prevNode.label` will give you an error. You can try it in the console, type `None.label`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor sets `self.prevNode` to `None`, and later you try to access `node.prevNode.label`, which is like trying to access `None.label`.  `None` doesn't have any attributes, so trying to access any will give you an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answers (and the error message) you are accessing `None.label`. If it is expected that `node` might be `None`, then you will need to check for it before appending it.

```
while node.label != node.prevNode.label:
    node = node.prevNode
    if node is not None:
        labels.append(node.label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) happens when attribute of the object is not available. An [attribute reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references) is a primary followed by a period and a name.

So basically you need to double check your object and the attribute name.

For example to return a list of valid attributes for that object, use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

```
dir(node)
```